# Grunt Watch is not work

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I want to monitor the css change by using Grunt Watch, but it doesn't work for my css folder. The following is my config in grunt file, the index.html page is monitored, but the css can't be. Please give some suggestions.

```
watch: {
  options: {
    livereload: true,
  },
  html: {
    files: ['index.html'],
  },
  js: {
    files: ['js/*.js'],
  },
  css: {
    files: ['css/*.css'],
  }
},
connect: {
  server: {
    options: {
      port: 9000,
      hostname: 'localhost',
      livereload: true,
      base:'',
      open: true
    }
  }
}
grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect', 'watch']);
```

Comment: What is your files/folders architecture?

Comment: Could you also post your grunt watch log when you're changing your css?

Answer (score 0):

```js
watch: {
    options: {
      livereload: true
    },
    html: {
      files: ['index.html']
    },
    js: {
      files: ['js/*.js']
    },
    css: {
      files: ['css/*.css']
    }
  },
  connect: {
    server: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: true,
        base: '',
        open: true
      }
    }
  }
grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect', 'watch']);
```

I think you have a few too many commas in some places, try the above